# How can i make a python server open an html file as deafult instead of directory?

Tags: python, server

here is an example for a simple server:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 80

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

the server itself works and the port is open but it opens the directory the code is in while i need it to open an html file that is in that directory.

How can i make it open the html file i want instead of the directory?

Comment: What URL are you using in the browser?

Comment: do you have index.html in that directory? I just checked your code and if I dont have index.html, it will show the files of that directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` and override the `do_GET` method to replace `self.path` with `your_file.html` if `/` is requested.

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = '/your_file.html'
        return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

Handler = MyRequestHandler
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), Handler)

server.serve_forever()
```

More: [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)